# Draw arrows ending at half circle

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to draw a fairly simple scene with tikz. 
[image]

The issue i have is with defining the end points on half circle. I tried to implement an algorithm
for intersection detection, pseudocode can be found at [Circle-Line intersection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073336/circle-line-collision-detection). However it does not work as it should. In addition, it does not compile if i use the `\ifthenelse` clause.

Any suggestions on how to get this to work?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{graphics, tkz-berge, tkz-graph}
%%%<
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{5pt}%
%%%>

\tikzset{isometricXYZ/.style={x={(-0.866cm,-0.5cm)}, y={(0.866cm,-0.5cm)}, z={(0cm,1cm)}}}

%% document-wide tikz options and styles
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} [scale=4, line join=round,
        opacity=.75, fill opacity=.35, text opacity=1.0,%
        >=latex,
        inner sep=0pt,%
        outer sep=2pt,%
    ]
% First argument is a ray angle, second argument is an offset along x-axis.
    \newcommand{\ray}[2]{
      \def\r{1} % sphere radius
      \def\l{2} % line length
      \def\xc{#2} % offset

      % Sphere center
      \def\Cx{0}
      \def\Cy{0}

      % Ray start
      \def\Ex{(\xc + (\l*cos(#1)))}
      \def\Ey{(\l*sin(#1))}

      % Ray end
      \def\Lx{\xc}
      \def\Ly{0}

      % Vector from ray start to end
      \def\dx{(\Lx -\Ex)}
      \def\dy{(\Ly -\Ey)}

      % Vector from ray start sphere center
      \def\fx{(\Ex - \Cx)}
      \def\fy{(\Ey - \Cy)}

      % solve eq
      \def\a{(\dx * \dx + \dy * \dy)}
      \def\b{(2 * \fx * \dx + \fy * \dy)}
      \def\c{(\fx * \fx + \fy * \fy - \r * \r)}
      \def\discriminant{(\b*\b - 4*\a*\c)}
      \ifthenelse{{\discriminant} < 0}
      {
          \def\endc{(\xc, 0)}
      }
      {
          \def\sqdiscriminant{sqrt(\discriminant)}
          \def\t{(-\b +\sqdiscriminant)/(2*\a)}
          \def\endc{({\Ex + \t*\dx}, {\Ey + \t*\dy})}
      }

      \def\startc{({\Ex}, {\Ey})}
      \draw [->] \startc -- \endc;
    }

    \draw[fill=gray, fill opacity=0.2] (1, 0) arc (0:180:1);

    \draw [dotted] (0, 0) -- ({cos(30)}, {sin(30)}) node[above right] {$\alpha_1$};
    \draw [dotted] (0, 0) -- ({cos(150)}, {sin(150)}) node[above left] {$\alpha_2$};
    \draw [dotted] (0, 0) -- (0, 1.1);

    \node[below right] (halfpi) at (1, 0) {$\frac{\pi}{2}$};
    \node[below left] (minushalfpi) at (-1, 0) {$-\frac{\pi}{2}$};

    \foreach \x in {2}
    {
      \ray{55}{\x}
    };

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I tested both solutions below, but in both cases i get some intersections picked up incorrectly. I guess that is because i take the first intersection in all cases, which is unfortunately not always the right one. Is there a way to always choose the **closest**, not the first, intersection?  [image]

p.p.s :)
nvm. I fixed it by reversing the path direction.

Comment: When trying to compile your example as given, I get `! Missing number, treated as zero.` on line 79.

Comment: The shorten option for the draw command is probably the best way to do it, now the difficult part is to find the intersection points between the arrows and the circle to compute the right length to remove.

Comment: @Thomas: No, the `intersections` library is the easiest way to calculate intersections. `;-)`

Comment: What about starting the arrows from the circle using polar coordinates?

Comment: @Luigi: That makes it difficult to space the rays evenly. You'd still have to calculate the polar angle by hand.

Comment: @Blaz: Just a hint: People who answered don't get notified when you edit the question. So you should either ask a new question (if it is a separate issue) or write a comment on the answers to ask for clarification.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can simply use the `intersections` library to avoid calculating the intersections of the rays and the circle manually. It even works for moderately complex paths like the combined half-circle-and-line path.

In order to get the intersection *closest* to the "light source", you can start the ray at the light source and then use the option `sort by=ray`. This way, `(interection-1)` is always the one closest to the source.

And yes, TikZ does all the calculation and sorting using `TeX`. Witchcraft!

[image: Many intersections]

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} [scale=4, line join=round, >=latex]
    % Name this path for intersections
    \draw[fill=gray, fill opacity=0.2, name path=outline]
        (-2,0) -- (-1,0) arc (180:0:1)-- (2,0) ;

    \draw [dotted] (0, 0) -- ({cos(30)}, {sin(30)}) node[above right] {$\alpha_1$};
    \draw [dotted] (0, 0) -- ({cos(150)}, {sin(150)}) node[above left] {$\alpha_2$};
    \draw [dotted] (0, 0) -- (0, 1.1);
    \node[below right] (halfpi) at (1, 0) {$\frac{\pi}{2}$};
    \node[below left] (minushalfpi) at (-1, 0) {$-\frac{\pi}{2}$};

    % Properties of the "light source"
    \def\angle{45}
    \def\width{2.8cm}

     % Draw the light source:
    \draw[very thick] (\angle:2.5cm) coordinate(light)
        ++(\angle+90:0.5*\width) -- +(\angle-90:\width);
    % Draw a number of rays:
    \foreach \x in {-8,...,8} {
        % Place a path from light source through circle and name it:
        \path[name path=ray,overlay] (light) ++(\angle+90:\x*\width/17)
            coordinate(start) -- +(180+\angle:5cm);
        % Draw the arrow from light source to first intersection:
        \draw[->, name intersections={of=outline and ray, sort by=ray}]
            (start) -- (intersection-1);
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @BlazBratanic: I've updated it with the "correct" solution for obtaining the intersection which is closest to the source.

Comment: @Fritz Thanks! Both for the fixed solution and for the clarification of the notification rules.

Answer (score 17):

If you want to selectively draw the intersection points then you can also implement whether an intersection is found or not. But intersection computation is a delicate thing and you can't always rely on its precision.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
\begin{scope}[fill opacity=.35]
\fill[blue] (4cm,0)--++(40:1cm) arc (40:180:1cm);
\fill[gray] (4cm,0)--++(40:1cm) arc (40:0:1cm);
\end{scope}
\draw[ultra thick] (1cm,2.5cm) coordinate (ls) -- ++(30:4cm) coordinate (le); 
\draw[ultra thick,name path=a] (2cm,-2cm)--++(7cm,0);
\draw[ultra thick,name path=b] (5cm,0) arc (0:180:1cm);
\foreach \x[count=\xi] in {0.1,0.15,...,0.9}{
\path[name path global=ray\xi,overlay] ($(ls)!\x!(le)$) --++(-60:15cm);
\draw[->,
    name intersections={of=a and ray\xi,name=intaray\xi},
    name intersections={of=b and ray\xi,name=intbray\xi}] 
\pgfextra{% Test for the shape name existence
\csname pgfutil@ifundefined\endcsname{pgf@sh@ns@intbray\xi-1}{\def\temp{a}}{\def\temp{b}}%
}
($(ls)!\x!(le)$) -- (int\temp ray\xi-1);
} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]